# How to implement hreflang for a .com with a subdomain and and a .ca domain

Tags: seo, subdomain, multiple-domains, internationalization, hreflang

I'm currently working on the SEO for a site that has the following domains:

- `subdomain.example.com`
- `example.ca`

These are both e-stores and I'm wondering how I would go about setting up hreflang in this circumstance?

Specifics: Both domains are different, but the store is the same and they have a lot of the same pages/products. One is meant to service Canada.

Comment: Assuming you've read the spec, what specifically is it you're not clear on?

Comment: `hreflang` references languages, not geographic regions. It is useful when you have a specific content in multiple languages, like English+French if you want support Canada, but it is not related to Canada as a geographic position. You can even specify `fr-CA` to specifically say `French as spoken in Canada` (because a little different than French spoken in France or in Belgium or in Switzerland, etc.) and `en-CA` for `Canadian English`.